# Using jQuery to renumber all the table rows after a row has been removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can the function below be modified such that the row count will start at 1 as opposed to being zero-based, and then if possible sort the table rows in ascending order (least to greatest).

Here is the code in question:

```
$("tr.highlighted").remove();

renumberRows()

function renumberRows() {

    $('#data tr').each(function(index, el){
        $(this).children('td').first().text(index++);
    });

}
```

Comment: How, and when, are rows removed?

Comment: To fix your code in the most minimal way, it would be `++index` or `index+1`. Pretty darn simple.

Comment: WRT sorting the table rows, do a search and you'll find plenty of solutions.

Comment: You should use CSS counters for that, not JS. google what I just said and learn it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use CSS counters (all non-counter related CSS removed for brevity):

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowCounter;
}

tr td:first-child {
    counter-increment: rowCounter;
}

td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowCounter);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pw9JP/)

The above, of course, uses a simple means of removing a row that may, or may not, resemble your own approach; this is, however, irrelevant as the CSS will automatically re-number the rows.

With jQuery, however, you'd need to explicitly re-count the `tr` elements once the `.remove()` has fired. If `remove()` allowed a callback function that'd be easy:

```
$(this).remove(function(){
    renumberRows();
});
```

But, of course, there is *no* provision for a callback in the `remove()` method. So, instead, we need to use `$.when()` and `.then()`:

```
$.when($(this).remove()).then(renumberRows);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pw9JP/3/)

Which basically calls the `renumberRows()` function once the `$(this).remove()` has been executed.

Though, having thought of a somewhat stupid-feeling solution I thought I'd try using:

```
$(this).remove(renumberRows());
```

Which, *against my expectations*, works: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Pw9JP/4/). And is somewhat simpler than using the `$.when().then()` chain.

References:

- CSS:

  - "[Using CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)."
  - [`::before` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/%3abefore).
  - [`::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after).
- jQuery:

  - [`jQuery.then()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.then/).
  - [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).